# Integrity Constraints violation error when deleting record in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new into Spring Boot framework, I want to implement an Entity Relationships so to achieve the following cases:

Consider the following example Entities Relationships

```java
@Entity
class Category {
  private Long id;
  private String name

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Entity
class Product {
  private Long id;
  private String name
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
  private Category category;
}
```

I use the below approach to delete objects with Jpa Repository API

```java
Product product = productRepository.getOne(productId);
productRepository.delete(product);

Category category = categoryRepository.getOne(categoryId);
categoryRepository.delete(category);
```

Based on the above relationships I want to be able to:

1. When deleting Category record, delete all related Products.
2. When deleting Product record, detach from the Category's products

I am aware of the cascade types but when deleting Category record I get constraints violation i.e. category x is still referenced into another table i.e. Products.

Comment: Can you add the code to depict the usage of cascade?

Comment: I have updated the code accordingly, Thanks!

Comment: Can you also mention how you are trying to delete entity? Share Repository code if possible? Or minimum reproducible example?